# Implementing SOLID - C#

Tags: c#

want to write this code in simplified way using SOLID principles. Any help would be highly appreciated.Can i implement inheritance to do this.

```
void CalculateTaxAndRewardPoints()
        {
            if (state == TEXAS)
            {
                rate = TX_RATE;
                amt = baseRate * TX_RATE;
                calc = 2 * basis(amt) + extra(amt) * 1.05;
            }
            else if ((state == OHIO) || (state == MAINE))
            {
                if (state == OHIO)
                    rate = OH_RATE;
                else
                    rate = MN_RATE;
                amt = baseRate * rate;
                calc = 2 * basis(amt) + extra(amt) * 1.05;
                if (state == OHIO)
                    points = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                rate = 1;
                amt = baseRate;
                calc = 2 * basis(amt) + extra(amt) * 1.05;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this code is about and fix the title? For now I downvoted your question for being very unspecific. I also vote to close it as being unclear-what-you-are-asking.

Comment: Just so it's said, MN is Minnesota, not Maine.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: The function doesn't do what it's name says - apparently it only calculates "reward points" for OHIO, and leaves the variable "points" unchanged or undefined for the others.

Comment: This looks like a homework question to me...

Comment: SOLID is to do with OOP, but your code is just a single method.  Unless your question is how to convert it to use objects/classes?

Answer (score 10):

I suggest to not operate by "cool" words like SOLID and just improve existing code. I don't know what type constants like `TEXAS` and `OHIO` of so I'll use enum for states. Your code can be simplified to (using C#7):

```
private static readonly Dictionary<State, double> Rates =
    new Dictionary<State, double>
    {
        [State.Texas] = TexasRate,
        [State.Ohio] = OhioRate,
        [State.Maine] = MaineRate
    };

public void CalculateTaxAndRewardPoints()
{
    rate = Rates.TryGetValue(state, out var r) ? r : 1;
    amt = baseRate * rate;
    calc = 2 * basis(amt) + extra(amt) * 1.05;

    if (state == State.Ohio)
        points = 2;
}
```

Using UPPERCASE_CONSTANTS_WITH_UNDERSCORES violates naming guidelines used in C#. Just use *PascalCased* names.

Comment: Should be remarked that this is C# 7.0 language version, no?

Comment: This is only more readable, not better designed.

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, thanks. I've added a note about it.

Comment: @ChrisWohlert I don't understand how we can talk about design seeing this single method :) My answer is just a simpler version of the original code.

Comment: @Maxim, well, I think it is important to note, that coding to "cool" words like SOLID is not a problem. It is a help to know how to "just improve existing code". Instead of giving poor advice, explain why SOLID does not really work for this small piece of functionality.

Comment: I think both of you have a point: blindly applying SOLID everywhere or using it as a replacement for actual thinking isn't the best possible approach, but that doesn't make them bad guidelines - especially for less experienced people it's better to (try to) follow them than to fumble around randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise, you could just improve the existing code like this:

```
void CalculateTaxAndRewardPoints()
{
    amt = baseRate;

    if (state == TEXAS)
        amt *= TX_RATE;
    else if (state == OHIO)
        amt *= OH_RATE;
    else if (state == MAINE)
        amt *= MN_RATE;

    calc = 2 * basis(amt) + extra(amt) * 1.05;
}
```

The calculation is always the same so it can be moved outside if the if's. Start with a baserate and multiple the state rates.

Comment: This violates the open/closed principle.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this was "solid". Assumes the calculation is the same per state. I would use an interface if the calculation was different as well.

```
class TexasCalculateTaxAndRewardPoints : CalculateTaxAndRewardPoints {  
    protected override decimal Rate { get { return 1.00; } }
}

class OhioCalculateTaxAndRewardPoints : CalculateTaxAndRewardPoints {

    protected override decimal Rate { get { return 1.01; } }

}

class MaineCalculateTaxAndRewardPoints : CalculateTaxAndRewardPoints {  
    protected override decimal Rate { get { return 1.02; } }
}

abstract class CalculateTaxAndRewardPoints 
{
    protected abstract decimal Rate { get; }

    public decimal Calculate() {
        return  2 * basis(Rate) + extra(Rate) * 1.05;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `points`?

Comment: Is it state specific? Just add it as another protected abstract decimal.

Comment: Seems overengineered, having a class for each state. Each method of calculating tax and rewards, yeah, that makes sense...But if the only difference between most states is the tax rate, a constructor parameter would carry far less baggage.

Comment: Yes it is over engineered- however the poster asked for an answer with inheritance...